# Is there any way to get around circular dependencies in Maven modules?

Tags: java, maven, groovy

I have two modules in my package, call them `Module1` and `Module2`. `Module1` has a dependency on `Module2` and would prefer to leave this alone (part of legacy code that I don't want to break).

There is a class that is part of `Module1` that I need to use in `Module2` - call it `Class1`. There are a couple wrapper objects around it and I don't care if they live in `Module1` or `Module2`. The problem is `Module1` already depends on `Module2` so I can't add a dependency for `Module2` on `Module1`. Is there any way at all to access `Class1` inside `Module2`? I suspect not but I'm not sure how to go about designing this feature without the dependencies in this direction (I've been thinking about interfaces, factories and adding a third module).

Any tips on designing so that this doesn't happen? If it matters, this is a Java/Groovy project.

Comment: If you can't pull out the part of `Module1` which induces the cyclical dependency, you're stuck. You're going to have to either accept the cyclical dependency or making a change to your legacy class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having cyclic dependency in your projects, it is basically due to bad design or issue in logical grouping of classes.

You can create new project and merge classes from both modules in it, if they are logically/functionally related to each other. You can use InteliJ analyse tool to find such cyclic dependent classes and improve your design.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to rewrite this legacy code so I found a different way to implement the change.

Comment: @tylk - care to share the approach you used in an answer?